# Custom Maven Plugin Development Archiving Files

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-plugin-development

I am developing my own custom Maven plugin and I want to archive the files. I followed this example: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-mojo-params.html and could archive the elements with zip format. However I want to use other formats too (user will indicate it). How can I set the archive type?

ZipArchiver works like that:

```
/**
* The Zip archiver.
* @parameter \
expression="${component.org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.Archiver#zip}"
*/
private ZipArchiver zipArchiver;
...
zipArchiver.addDirectory( buildDirectory, includes, excludes );
zipArchiver.setDestFile( new File( baseDirectory, "output.zip" ) );
zipArchiver.createArchive();
```

Comment: You know about things like maven-assembly-plugin and truezip-maven-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am developing an all-in one plugin

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a format property to your plugin and use the relevant archiver depending on your format:

```
Archiver archiver = null;
if("zip".equals(format)){
    archiver = new ZipArchiver(...);
}
else if("tar".equals(format)){
    archiver = new TarArchiver(...);
}
else (...){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. My answrer us inspired by the Assembly plugin source code.

Comment: It says: else if ( "zip".equals( string ) ||"jar".equals( string ) ) { archiverStub = new JarArchiverStub();  at source code?